# How to display name and email inside material UI chip?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI chip to display name and email side by side.
But when name is large email goes out of the chips boundary

This is my function returning chips

```
  getGuestList() {
    let {guests} = this.state;
    let guestChips = [];
    let s = {overflow: 'hidden',width: '50%', display: 'inline-flex'}
    guests.map((guest, i) => {
      guestChips.push(
        <div key={i}>
          <Chip
            onRequestDelete={() => {this.removeGuest(i)}}
            style={{marginTop: 10, width: '225%'}}
            labelStyle={{width: '97%'}}
          >

          <div><div style={s}>
            <div style={{textOverflow: 'ellipsis'}}>
            {guest.name}
            </div>
          </div> | <div style={s}>{guest.email ? guest.email : ''}</div></div>
          </Chip>
        </div>
      )
    });
```

this displays both but their width is fixed to 50%, so in case if email is  smaller there is space remain on the side of email and if name is small space remain on the side of email.

Is there a way to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandeep, if your intent is to put paragraph length text inside of a chip, you should consider a redesign of your UI because this is not what material-ui's chips were meant for nor for that matter what google's material specs intended them for. Who really has emails that have the maximum number of characters(254) anyways??

Getting into the chip component's functionality, they do size properly without that weird spacing you have shown me in that image. However, they are not flex items and therefore not responsive. If you're experiencing the css issues still, you must have some custom css that you've implemented that is overriding what material-ui provided and it's causing it to break. I've attached an image showing how I do not experience your style issues with my code. Speaking of custom css, you could completely avoid this entire issue just by setting a max-width on your chips and then use text-overflow: ellipsis.

[image: see here]

Comment: Totally on board with not apt use of material ui chip, but it was needed so still trying,appreciate all you did

Answer (score 0):

I put this together for you completely based on the example one material-ui's site. Specifically the "Example Array" example. http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/chip.

For what you're looking for, you really should not need to do much more than what they provided except perhaps make changes to the value names.

I will note that I'm using the latest version of Material-UI. The example they use, what I have provided you however hasn't changed for many versions. So it should work for you. I'm also running latest compatible versions of React/ReactDOM. If this doesn't work for you, then you should consider upgrading to the 16.0 distro if you haven't already.

```
import React from 'react';
import Chip from 'material-ui/Chip';
const outsideDataSource = [
    {
        key: 1,
        email: "Bob.Bobberson@gmail.com",
        name: "Bob Bobberson"
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        email: "Abigail@gmail.com",
        name: "Abigail Person"
    },
    {
        key: 3,
        email: "third.person@gmail.com",
        name: "Third Person"
    }
]

export default class EmailList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        guestList: outsideDataSource
    }
}
handleRequestDelete = (key) => {
    this.guestList = this.state.guestList;
    const chipToDelete = this.guestList.map((chip) => chip.key).indexOf(key);
    this.guestList.splice(chipToDelete, 1);
    this.setState({guestList: this.guestList});
}
renderGuestList(guest) {
    return (
        <Chip
            key={guest.key}
            onRequestDelete={() => this.handleRequestDelete(guest.key)}
            style={{display: 'inline-block', marginLeft: '10px', marginBottom: '10px'}}
            labelStyle={{verticalAlign: 'top'}}
        >
            {guest.name}: {guest.email}
        </Chip>
    )
}
render() {
    const {guestList} = this.state
    return (
        <div>
            {guestList.map(this.renderGuestList, this)}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Problem not solved - http://imgur.com/a/9hAHP - As you can see wer side with your solution if name is long , it going right outside the window and in my solution there is space on either side of name and email , if there length is small... want to reduce size of chip based on size of name and email just before the date window

Answer (score 0):

try this way but change value with yours

```
 <Chip     
  label={user['user.firstname'] + ' ' + user['user.lastname']}
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use a custom component, you can try the following in place of Chip

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import React from 'react';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: '4px',
    backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
    display: 'inline-flex',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    borderRadius: '16px',
  },
  label: {
      padding: 10,
      margin: 0,
  }  
});

class MultiLineChip extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
          <Typography variant="body2" gutterBottom className={classes.label}>
            {this.props.label || ''}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MultiLineChip);
```